# Имеются ли в современных языках программирования (C#, Python и др.) стандартные средства для описания интервалов и операций с ними?

Tags: python, c#, множества

В ответе [Как описать средствами ООП математический интервал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589400/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB-ddd) показано, как описать класс интервалов, включающий такие операции с интервалами как пересечение, объединение, вычисление покрытия и т.д. Ответ был дан в 2016 году. Хотелось бы знать имеются ли в современных языках программирования C#,  Python и др. (исключая Kotlin) стандартные средства для описания этого класса? Имеется ли в них такой класс как объединение непересекающихся интервалов?
Вопрос был задан в связи с тем, что я готовлю статью с предварительным названием «Математическая модель вопроса». В ней используется математический аппарат [алгебры кортежей](https://habr.com/ru/articles/750790/), в которой многоместные отношения представлены как объединения декартовых произведений и их дополнения. Тогда в простейшем случае **вопрос** – это декартово произведение, в котором неизвестный атрибут задан множеством или интервалом. А **ответ** на него получается с помощью вычисления пересечения вопроса с отношением или соединением отношений.

Для описания модели потребовалось определить типы данных для атрибутов. Понятно, что в данном случае тип «множество» один из основных. А какой тип выбрать в случаях, когда атрибуты представлены числами или интервалами? Сначала хотел сам построить алгоритмы для операций пересечения, объединения и дополнения интервалов или их объединений. При этом хотел использовать только замкнутые интервалы типа [a,b] с частным случаем [a,a] для обозначения точек (открытые или полуоткрытые интервалы здесь можно добавить в качестве частного случая). Уже придумал алгоритмы, в том числе и алгоритм преобразования объединения произвольных интервалов в объединение непересекающихся интервалов. Но решил узнать, решалась ли подобная задача до этого.

Comment: На сколько я знаю, в C# нету стандартно такого функционала. Отдаленно, не так давно, появились `Range`, но это не то, что вам нужно. Правда я не знаю зачем вам "стандартные" средства, когда подобное пишется самостоятельно в несколько строк кода ([первый пример из гугла](https://gist.github.com/hongymagic/877f1e083d5f0855597a)), ну и уверен, что есть какая либо библиотека в NuGet с подобным решением.

Comment: В C# есть LINQ. IEnumerable имеет методы Union, Intersect и пр. Не подойдёт?

Comment: `sympy` поддерживает типы для множеств чисел. В том числе интервалы всех видов и операции над ними. [sets](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html).

Comment: Я в прошлом году писал свои интервалы для питона, там кода не так уж много получается на самом деле. Правда, код дать не могу - писал для одной конторы, весь код остался там.

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, современные языки общего назначения и их стандартный инструментарий предназначены только для быстрой разработки типовых приложений, как бы цинично это ни звучало. Математическую экзотику в виде множеств или интервалов нужно искать либо в специализированных языках с уклоном в математический аппарат, либо писать самостоятельно. Конечно есть шанс найти библиотеку от энтузиастов, но зачастую быстрее дописать нужное самому.